# Does enabling GPS via this android intent also gives app ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permissions?

Tags: android, android-intent, gps

So I have this line of code below which basically opens a new intent which shows the option for user to turn on gps.

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
```

Now I would like to use access_fine_location for the gps. Does doing the above automatically also gives us fine location access permissions as if I had ran the  below code or do I need to run the below code with the above one?

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
```

Comment: i hope it does.

Comment: You have to ask for permission.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. Your first snippet opens the Location settings, where you can set Location accuracy. It doesn't mean you have got the location permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
```

Above code only navigates user to settings window. It does not provide or include direct permission of access location which is below.

**Where As**

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
```

This code ask for permission of access location which must be require to get user location.
In short, second one (permission) code must be require where as first code means navigates location Settings is optional but it is good programming to give alert to turn on GPS and direct navigates to settings window. Yes, you need both codes.